# Compilation of code with other version of java

Tags: java

I develop a program that requires the jdk version 1.6 but i am restricted with jdk1.4. When I try to compile my code using jdk1.4 the compiler gives the the compilation error for the following code.

```
symbol  : class PrivateKeyEntry
location: class java.security.KeyStore
       KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry =(KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)ks.getEntry("");

symbol  : class PasswordProtection
location: class java.security.KeyStore
                    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("shivambp2014".toCharArray()));
```

My client also uses the jdk1.4 version. please guide, how do i get rid of this compilation error so i can compile the code correctly.

Comment: Please, post the full compilation error.

Comment: Class `PrivateKeyEntry` was added with [Java 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry.html). You will probably have to refactor your code.

Comment: Hi Drux, you are right, this class is also available in jdk1.5 and with jdk 1.5 my code compiled and run successfully. I downloaded one jar file that have same classes and I put that jar in the classpath and then compiled the code but result is same.

Comment: Given how many years java 1.4 has been without security updates, your first action should be to try and persuade your clients to upgrade to a version that is supported by oracle, i.e. 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have to upgrade your Java or change the code to use only the things available in your chosen Java version.

From the error message I am guessing there is need for some kind of encryption. You might be able to use [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org/) instead of tools provided by JDK. This depends on the code you are working with.

Also one might also just try and remove the lines that do not compile and see what gets broken and then start building up only the necessary features again with the tools you can use.

Changes from 1.4 to 1.5 are quite big, it is likely that there is too much code for you to change...

Maybe you should persuade your client to update more recent Java. Garbage collection abilities among many other things have developed greatly. Java 1.4 has reached it's "end of life" in [2008](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-138567.html).

Answer (score 0):

`PrivateKeyEntry`  were introduced in JDK 1.5. So you can't use them in 1.4. However, you may be able to use `JDK 1.5` compiler  with `-target jsr14`  and `-source 1.5` option in javac  command

Comment: This should work as long as no Java 1.5 specific code is required while running.

Comment: If it is failing because of PrivateKeyEntry class.The doc says PrivateKeyEntry was added since 1.5 so this should do the job

Comment: Yes, I know.
But JDK 1.4 does not recognize source level 1.5 or above.

Comment: -target jsr14,which is equivalent to the 1.4 option – except that it permits a source code format of 1.5

Comment: I know what the parameters do. But 1.4 javac won't know anything about 1.5. It does not allow setting source or target level to 1.4.